# Converting drag and drop application that shows directory into showing hash

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, md5

I am having trouble converting this code into allowing me to drop files into my application and my application create a message box saying its md5 hash code. Currently, I have the code to give the directory of the file I dropped in.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    For Each path In files
        MsgBox(path)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Any ideas, I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have most of the code you need, only needs a function to calculate the md5, and then you can plug that into your message box:

```
MsgBox(ComputeMD5Hash(path))
```

Here is the function, taken mostly from this [Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301053/en-us)

```
Private Function ComputeMD5Hash(ByVal path As String) As String
    Dim tmpSource() As Byte
    Dim tmpHash() As Byte
    'Create a byte array from source data.
    tmpSource = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(path)
    'Compute hash based on source data.
    tmpHash = New Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(tmpSource)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sOutput As New System.Text.StringBuilder(tmpHash.Length)
    For i = 0 To tmpHash.Length - 1
        sOutput.Append(tmpHash(i).ToString("X2"))
    Next
    Return sOutput.ToString()
End Function
```

In-case you want to drop a directory and get all the hashes of the files inside you first need to check if you're dealing with a file or a folder, if its a folder you loop over all the files inside and call the function for each one, which would make your *DragDrop* event handler look something like this, and have the added benefit both files and folders can be taken care of.

```
Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    For Each path In files
        If IO.File.GetAttributes(path) = FileAttribute.Directory Then
            'Dealing with a Directory
            Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
            Dim fiArr As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
            Dim fri As IO.FileInfo
            For Each fri In fiArr
                MessageBox.Show(fri.FullName & " " & ComputeMD5Hash(fri.FullName))
            Next fri
        Else
            'Dealing with a File
            MessageBox.Show(path & " " & ComputeMD5Hash(path))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```